# Electrical components failing in a Poisson process

Tags: probability, self-study, stochastic-processes

A machine has infinitely many identical components. They fail according to a Poisson process with rate λ = 4/hour. A repairman arrives at time t and instantly repairs all of the broken components, but components cost more to fix the longer they have been broken. The cost to repair a component is $10/hour it has been down.

Suppose that all components are functional at time t=0. What is the expected cost of the repairs at time t hours?

(Example for clarification: if one component fails at time t=3.5 and another at time t=4, and the repairman arrives at time t=5, then the total cost would be 15+10=25.)

My thinking for this problem so far is as follows. The expected number of failures is λt=4t. The expected mean downtime for these broken components should be t/2. Thus, the expected cost of repairs is the product (4t)(t/2)(10 per hour), or 20(t^2). Is this line of reasoning correct? Thanks. This was a homework assignment.

Comment: "*A machine has infinitely many identical components*" ... at this point I can't help but think "... okay, so we're talking about being in a black hole singularity and every component failed via spaghettification before the machine was even a fraction ($\epsilon$, for arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$) completed". [Who writes questions this way? The Poisson process is a *model*; it ought to be used as one.]